# Print HTML (with Images) to PDF in SwiftUI

Tags: html, pdf, swiftui, webkit

I am trying to convert an existing project to SwiftUI.  I create an HTML string and use it to create a PDF file.  Sadly, WebKit functionality such as createPDF(configuration:completionHandler:) isn't accessible under SwiftUI.  The following allows me to display the html correctly, but makePDF() throws the error "Specified target process does not exist".

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "html") {
            WebView(request: URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }   
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let request: URLRequest

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
        self.myUtility(uiView: uiView)
    }
    
    func myUtility(uiView: WKWebView) {
        let pdfConfiguration = WKPDFConfiguration()
        pdfConfiguration.rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 810.0, height: 810.0 * 297.0 / 210.0)
                
        uiView.createPDF(configuration: pdfConfiguration) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let docFolders = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
                    guard let docFolder = docFolders.first else { return }
                    
                    let pdfURL = docFolder.appendingPathComponent("Output.pdf")
                    
                    try data.write(to: pdfURL)
                } catch {}
            case .failure:
                print(result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Taking a different approach I've tried using UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter, and I can successfully produce a PDF of text, but not images.  This is a well documented issue.  Some have suggested converting the image to base64 and inserting inline into the HTML string, but this doesn't work for many, including me.

I'm really surprised that this is so difficult because I would have thought that sharing a page would be quite a common requirement.  If anyone has managed to make either of these two approaches work, or if there is a different approach that I haven't considered, please educate me!

Comment: "makePDF() throws the error"  You aren't throwing an error.  So could you tell us how you get the said error?

Comment: Poor word choice on my part. If I call makePDF(), the createPDF enclosure doesn’t execute and I get this error in the debug console.

Comment: Well, you are not setting anything to your `URLRequest` guy.  So that's not surprising.

Comment: Maybe I’ve misunderstood, but I pass the URLRequest when I create the WebView.

Comment: I've updated the code to make my implementation a bit more obvious

Comment: I think an issue is not how you print the web page content.  For example, if I try to create the web content at apple.com with `PDFDocument`, a resulting PDF file contains no images.  And the same is true if I print out the content with Firefox.